# MongoDB multikeys on _id + some value

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB I have a query which looks like this to find out for which comments the user has already voted:

```
db.comments.find({
    _id: { $in: [...some ids...] },
    votes.uid: "4fe1d64d85d4f4c00d000002"
});
```

As the documentation says you should have

> One index per query

So what's better creating a multikey on _id + votes.uid or is it enough to just index on votes.uid because Mongo handles _id automatically in any way?

Comment: you don't need a multikey, but i would only add an index to `votes.uid` if queries become too slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is automatically an index on **_id**.

Depending of your *queries* (how many ids you have in the $in array) and your *data*, (how many votes you have on one object) you may create a index on votes.uid.

Take care of which index is used during query execution and remember you can force Mongo to use the index you want by adding `.hints(field:1)` or `hints('indexname')`